How to use dependent fields in the Slack wrokflow?
I built a slack bot and i have to build a workflow through which users can submit some requests , so i created a basic workflow but i need to make it more dynamic like let’s say i choose an option from a drop down menu , i need to add more dropdowns for that particular option which i choose.
The code that I tried:
import { DefineWorkflow, Schema } from "deno-slack-sdk/mod.ts";
import { DropDownValue1Function } from "../functions/greeting_function.ts";

const GreetingWorkflow = DefineWorkflow({
callback_id: "greeting_workflow",
title: "Send a greeting",
description: "Send a greeting to channel",
input_parameters: {
properties: {
interactivity: {
type: Schema.slack.types.interactivity,
},
channel: {
type: Schema.slack.types.channel_id,
},
},
required: \["interactivity"\],
},
});

const inputForm = GreetingWorkflow.addStep(
Schema.slack.functions.OpenForm,
{
title: "Send a greeting",
interactivity: GreetingWorkflow.inputs.interactivity,
submit_label: "Send greeting",
fields: {
elements: \[
{
name: "recipient",
title: "Recipient",
type: Schema.slack.types.user_id,
},
{
name: "channel",
title: "Channel to send message to",
type: Schema.slack.types.channel_id,
default: GreetingWorkflow.inputs.channel,
},
{
name: "message",
title: "Message to recipient",
type: Schema.types.string,
long: true,
},
{
name: "dropDownValue1",
title: "Select a Value:",
type: Schema.types.string,
enum: \["value 1", "value 2", "value 3"\],
},
{
name: "dropDownValue2",
title: "Select a Value 2:",
type: Schema.types.string,
enum: \["value 1", "value 2", "value 3"\],
},
\],
required: \["recipient", "channel", "message", "dropDownValue1"\],
},
},
);

// Define the step for dynamically updating dropDownValue2 based on dropDownValue1 selection
const dropDownValue2Step = GreetingWorkflow.addStep(
DropDownValue1Function,
{
dropDownValue1: inputForm.outputs.fields.dropDownValue1,
},
);

export default GreetingWorkflow;

and the custom function code:
// greeting_function.ts

import { DefineFunction, Schema,SlackFunction } from "deno-slack-sdk/mod.ts";

export const DropDownValue1Function = DefineFunction({
  callback_id: "drop_down_value_1_function",
  title: "Process DropDownValue1 Selection",
  description: "Process selection of dropDownValue1 and update dropDownValue2 options",
  source_file: "functions/greeting_function.ts",
  input_parameters: {
    properties: {
      dropDownValue1: {
        type: Schema.types.string,
        description: "The value selected from dropDownValue1",
      },
    },
    required: ["dropDownValue1"],
  },
  output_parameters: {
    properties: {
      dropDownValue2: {
        type: Schema.types.string,
        description: "The options for dropDownValue2",
      },
    },
    required: ["dropDownValue2"],
  },
});

export default SlackFunction(
  DropDownValue1Function,
  async ({ inputs }) => {
    const { dropDownValue1 } = inputs;

    let secondDropdownOptions: string[] = [];

    // Determine options for dropDownValue2 based on dropDownValue1 selection
    switch (dropDownValue1) {
      case "value 1":
        secondDropdownOptions = ["value1_option1", "value1_option2"];
        break;
      case "value 2":
        secondDropdownOptions = ["value2_option1", "value2_option2"];
        break;
      case "value 3":
        secondDropdownOptions = ["value3_option1", "value3_option2"];
        break;
      default:
        secondDropdownOptions = ["default 1", "default 2", "default 3"];
        break;
    }

    // Convert the array of options to a comma-separated string
    const dropdownValue2 = secondDropdownOptions.join(",");


    return { outputs: { dropDownValue2: dropdownValue2 } };
  },
);

I want the options of dropDown2 to be dependent on dropDown1.
